# No 'que' after 'après'

Tags: grammaire

> Travaillez votre foutu cardio, après il est jamais trop tard.

Why in this sentence is *que* not following *après*?

I would imagine that *que* follows *après* when using indicative tense.

Comment: The sentence is weird, because we expect the future after the adverb "après" (*afterwards*), like if you replace it by "demain" (tomorrow*).

Comment: @Graffito Not necessarily, especially for a *vérité générale*, e.g. *Et je n'en suis pas fâché, parce que vois-tu, si on ne se marie pas à mon âge, après il est trop tard...* Georges Feydeau

Comment: This looks like spoken French, is it from a youtube video? If so, adding the link and timecode would help a lot

Answer (score 3):

I take *après* here to be adding another good reason to do the cardio. "In any case." You could also think of it as meaning "after all" (*après tout*) or "besides" (*après toutes ces raisons il y en a une autre*).

> Fine, do your damn cardio. In any case, it's never too late.

This usage is considered informal. A standard alternative might be *en tout cas*, and a formal alternative might be *il faut admettre que*.

A somewhat subtle discourse note: the *foutu* suggests a context where either (a) the person who should do the cardio has insisted on doing so and annoyed the speaker, who is here giving in but also conceding that there's a good reason to do so, or (b) the person who should do the cardio is refusing to and needs to be told to do it, and hence needs an extra motivation. Either context licences the "but also" sense of *après*.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is odd without context but I guess its meaning is:

> Work your bloody cardio. Later/after/that said*, it's never too late.

(*Thanks @StéphaneGimenez)

With *que*, we would use the subjunctive but the sentence becomes meaningless:

> *Travaillez votre foutu cardio, après qu'il (ne) soit/est jamais trop tard.*

> Work your bloody cardio after that it is never too late. (??: i.e. "Don't work your cardio before it is never too late.")

What would work with *que* is:

> *Travaillez votre foutu cardio avant qu'il ne soit trop tard.*

> Work your bloody cardio before it's too late.

Comment: Même si la ponctuation est douteuse, je n'arrive à comprendre ce « après » que comme la variante orale de « cela dit ». Si c'est bien le cas, le contexte reste très flou et je suppose que l'extrait est tronqué, parce que ça appelle une suite, ou au monis nécessite un certain préambule. Mais, j'ai vraiment du mal à imaginer que ce soit un vrai « après ». Après, je peux me tromper ;-)

Comment: Une autre possibilité, peut-être, serait qu'une virgule aurait été oubliée: _Travaillez votre foutu cardio, après, il est jamais trop tard_. Dans ce cas, ce _après_ n'aurait plus de sens temporel, mais indiquerait juste un ajout à la conversation. Après, Stéphane l'a déjà mentionné :-)

Comment: "après qu'il (ne) soit" : [pas de subjonctif](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/apres-que) suivant "après que", même si l'indicatif sonne mal.

Comment: @Graffito Si tu veux mais *après qu'il n'est jamais trop tard* et *après qu'il ne soit jamais trop tard* sonnent tout aussi mal l'un que l'autre. C'était de toute façon un exemple de phrase qui n'a pas de sens.